# Вычисление определенного интеграла методом прямоугольников

Tags: c++

Вот написал простенькую прогу по вычислению определенного интеграла методом прямоугольников.
Но что-то в консоли ничего не выводится.
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
float f(float x)
{
    return(1+sin(x)/(1+cos(x)));
}
float integralpram(int a,int b,int n)
{
    float h,S,x;
    int i;
    h=(b-a)/n;
    S=0;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        x=a+i*h;
        S=S+f(x);
    }
    S=h*S;
    return S;
}
void main()
{
   float  y;
   y=integralpram(1,5,10);
   cout<<y;
   system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: У Вас функция не является ограниченной в точке x=pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому как вычисленное значение h равно нулю. (5-1) / 10 == 0, а Вы ожидаете 0.4.

Пишите, к примеру, так:

```
h=(b-a) * 1.0 /n;
```

Comment: Или задавать a и b как float.

Comment: Лучше привести тип `n` к float. Получим

    h = (b - a) / (float)n;

Comment: По существу, `a` и `b`, как границы интегрирования, должны быть типа `float`.

Точнее, `double`, т. к. экономить пару байт на различии уже давно не необходимость (а вычисления с `double` быстрее и точнее).

Answer (score 0):

Или так h = (double)(b - a) / n;
XD

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;
float f(float x)
{
    return(1+sin(x)/(1+cos(x)));
}
float integralpram(int a,int b,int n)
{
    float h,S,x;
    int i;
    h=(b-a) * 1.0 /n;
    S=0;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        x=a+i*h;
        S=S+f(x);
    }
    S=h*S;
    return S;
}
int main()
{
   float  y;
   y=integralpram(1,5,10);
   cout<<y;
   system("PAUSE");
}
```